# Empty object in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

While reading bloc plugin document, I encountered this code. My question is why do we need the empty static class here. If we want to check null, we alread have the null check `?` feature.

The code:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class User extends Equatable {
  const User(this.id);

  final String id;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];

  static const empty = User('-');
}
```

Original screenshot of the content
[image]

Reference to the content:
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial?id=user-repository

Comment: Posting the scrrenshot of the code is bad practise in the SO. Please post the entire code .

Answer (score 4):

In the real world project, you will encounter some case you cannot use null safety, for example if you have a function have been used many place, and you cannot change it (real world maintain problem):

```
// This function cannot be edit for many reason
String getUserId(User user) {
  return user.id;
}
```

Then if you have a nullable `user`, you cannot pass an it to above function, and I have seen many people try to call above function like this:

```
final String userId = getUserId(user ?? User("-"));
```

And when this happen, it will be bad practice, because if project has many developers, each person will has their own way to decide what user will be the empty `User`. Many instance they can think about: `User("-")`, `User("-1")`, `User("")`, ...

Then the empty static value above will solve this problem, every one will use `User.empty` as a uniformity

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation. Is there any other case that can be used this strategy.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there any other situation which this code is useful.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like the author was maybe trying to use the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

That pattern was thought out when "nullability" meant any object could be null at any time and your code would have been a nightmare of if/else branches if you wanted to make it really safe.

With Darts very cool [Sound Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety#:%7E:text=Sound%20null%20safety%20changes%20potential,Been%20assigned%20a%20null%20value.) I personally don't see a reason why it would be useful, but I guess everybody uses the patterns they like.

If you want to understand why it is there, just test it: delete it, then fix all the errors that pop up at compile time, test it at runtime, and then figure out which version you like better. Maybe it serves a purpose you don't see yet.

Comment: In your current code, do you prefer the code with sound null safety to the code with the empty object in the example